# Dynamic Reports - is it possible to set starting page?

Tags: pdf, dynamic-reports

I'm using Dynamic Reports to build huge PDF files (like 80.000 pages) and for now, the solution I found was to create intermediary files and merge them after processing. The last challenge for getting it done is to add page numbers, but the default counting obviously get messed up after merging. So I need some way to set the starting page number when creating the temp PDF files. The three methods available don't allow page setting. Is it possible? How do I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Although it's hard to find in the documentation, the report() has exactly what is needed: the method

```
report.setStartPageNumber(int)
```

As stated by Ricardo in the DynamicReports forum.